# how to make grand parent and parent uncheck only till all child checkbox is unselected

Tags: jquery, ajax

The given below is my code, The functioning should work like that when I checked all the child i.e abc, def and ghi. Then its parent and grand parent(Property, Edit Property must also get selected) and when Property and Edit Property must get unselected only when abc, def and ghi are unselected. This functioning does not work in my code, Please help. The given below is my code, edit it without altering the html code. Use jQuery and Ajax.

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
  ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="parent" name="Property" />Property
    <ul>
      <li id="Edit_Property">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Edit_Property" />Edit_Property
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="id_abc" name="abc">abc</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="id_abc" name="abc">def</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="id_abc" name="abc">ghi</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="Remove_Property">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Remove_Property" />Remove_Property
      </li>
      <li id="Add_Property">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Add_Property" />Add_Property
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="parent" name='Testimonial' />Testimonial
    <ul>
      <li id="Add">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Add" />Add
      </li>
      <li id="Remove">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Remove" />Remove
      </li>
      <li id="View">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="View" />View
      </li>
      <li id="Edit">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Edit" />Edit
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<script>
 $(function() {
  $(document).on("change", "li:has(li) > input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().prev('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
    $(this).siblings('ul').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
  $(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox'] ~ ul input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().prev('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
    $(this).closest("li:has(li)").children("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', $(this).closest('ul').find("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked'));
  });
})
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("change", "li:has(li) > input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().prev('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
    $(this).siblings('ul').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
  $(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox'] ~ ul input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    var countcheckedchild = $(this).parent().parent().siblings().find(":checkbox:checked").length;
    if(countcheckedchild == 0){//if all siblings of ul are unchecked
     $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().prev('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
    $(this).closest("li:has(li)").children("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', $(this).closest('ul').find("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked'));
    }
  });
})
```

```css
 ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="parent" name="Property" />Property
    <ul>
      <li id="Edit_Property">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Edit_Property" />Edit_Property
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="id_abc" name="abc">abc</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="id_abc1" name="abc">def</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="id_abc2" name="abc">ghi</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="Remove_Property">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Remove_Property" />Remove_Property
      </li>
      <li id="Add_Property">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Add_Property" />Add_Property
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="parent" name='Testimonial' />Testimonial
    <ul>
      <li id="Add">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Add" />Add
      </li>
      <li id="Remove">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Remove" />Remove
      </li>
      <li id="View">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="View" />View
      </li>
      <li id="Edit">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="Edit" />Edit
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When I select Edit Property and Remove Property, Its working fine. But after that if I unselect Edit Property, Edit Property and its child must get unselected and  Property must not get unselected(since Remove Property is already selected)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
Now You can check this https://jsfiddle.net/shantaram/a9Lxuyts/

you have used same id's `id=id_abc`

```js
$(function() {
 $(document).on('change','#id-property', function(){
  var $this = $(this);
        $('.child-property').each(function( index ){
     $(this).prop('checked', $this.is(':checked'));
        });
        $('#id-edit-property').trigger('change');
  });
  $(document).on('change','#id-edit-property', function(){
  var $this = $(this);
   $('.class-children').each(function( index ){
   $(this).prop('checked', $this.is(':checked'));
    });
  });
  $(document).on('change','.child-property', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
      $('#id-property').prop('checked', $('.child-property:checked').length > 0 );
  });
  $(document).on('change','.class-children', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
      $('#id-property').prop('checked', $('.class-children:checked').length > 0 );
      $('#id-edit-property').prop('checked', $('.class-children:checked').length > 0 );
      $('#id-property').prop('checked', $('.child-property:checked').length > 0 );
  });
  $(document).on('change','.testimonial', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.child-testimonial').each(function( index ){
      $(this).prop('checked', $this.is(':checked'));
    });
  });
  $(document).on('change','.child-testimonial', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
      $('#id-testimonial').prop('checked', $('.child-testimonial:checked').length > 0 );
  });
})
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="parent property" id="id-property" name="Property" />Property
    <ul>
      <li id="Edit_Property">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child child-property" id="id-edit-property" name="Edit_Property" />Edit_Property
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="class-children" id="id_abc" name="abc">abc</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="class-children" id="id_def" name="abc">def</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="class-children" id="id_ghi" name="abc">ghi</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="Remove_Property">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child child-property" name="Remove_Property" />Remove_Property
      </li>
      <li id="Add_Property">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child child-property" name="Add_Property" />Add_Property
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="parent testimonial" id="id-testimonial" name='Testimonial' />Testimonial
    <ul>
      <li id="Add">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child child-testimonial" name="Add" />Add
      </li>
      <li id="Remove">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child child-testimonial" name="Remove" />Remove
      </li>
      <li id="View">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child child-testimonial" name="View" />View
      </li>
      <li id="Edit">
        <input type="checkbox" class="child child-testimonial" name="Edit" />Edit
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Property gets selected only when I click on edit property, It also must get selected when I select either remove property and edit property. Similarly Testimonial must get selected when I either select add, remove, view or edit. Please suggest

Comment: is this ok if I add extra classes to html elements?

Comment: Is this your fixed HTML structure, or dynamic ?

Comment: is this your fixed HTML structure, or dynamic ?

Comment: Its a dynamic html structure. u can add classes to the existing elements

Comment: Test My updated https://jsfiddle.net/shantaram/a9Lxuyts/ , and let me know